How To Join Two Shapes and act like one Shape?
Konvajs How To Join Two Shapes and act like one Shape ?
For example, I have Two Konva.Text like this
const text = new Konva.Text({
  text : 'First Text',
  fill : 'blue'
});

const text2 = new Konva.Text({
  text : 'Second Text',
  fill : 'red'
});


I want to join both text and add the stroke + strokeWidth ..
I can add stroke + strokeWidth individually, but the stroke didn't quite match to each other since it act as different shape ..
I can't use Konva.Group, since it doesn't have stroke parameter ..

Group mainly allows you to move and transform the shapes together. If you want them to share things like styling, I'd recommend you use a shared variable between the two Text shapes.
